# Is it possible to rename a process class window name?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Is that possible in c++ ? ( platform : windows )

note : i'm not the owner of the process

Comment: What does "process class window name" mean?

Comment: @JonathanPotter sorry for not being clear or what exactly it's called here is an example : FindWindow (ClassName , WindowName) I can change simply the "WindowName" by using SetWindowText but how to change the "ClassName". I hope i was clear

Comment: You can't change the class of an existing window. Why would you even want to?

Comment: Okay because some hacks use "ClassName" instead of the WindowName or process pid to find the window or the exe inorder to patch it. Any work out for this?Thanks

Comment: If it's your window you could use a random class name that changes every time you start up.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my window :/ Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the SetWindowsHookEx function to set a global WH_MSGFILTER hook. This code must be in a DLL. This causes the DLL to be injected into all processes, including the process that owns the window whose name you wish to change.
2. In your executable that loaded the DLL, use FindWindow to find the window handle of the window that you wish to change.
3. Post a message to that window.
4. Handle that message in your MessageProc hook procedure.
5. Change the name of the window to your hearts content using the same techniques you would use if the window was in your own process.

Caveats: For security reasons, this will only work if you have code signed the executable and DLL on Windows Vista and later if UAC is enabled.

Comment: Isn't there a way without dll injection though i didnt try that for example we use SetWindowText to change window title name isn't there a function or a simple way to change the class name ?